# Construct a dictionary from a list where each value will contain complements of the current key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm writing a Python function called `everyone_sign()` that takes a list of names and returns a dictionary where the keys are the names and the values are goodbye messages signed by only the other names.  The name keys cannot sign their own cards.  My problem is finding a way to output all the names except the current key for each iteration

So far I have

```
def everyone_sign(names):

    message = "Thank You!, Your Friends, "
    space = ", "
    message_Dict = {}

    for i in range(len(names)):
        message = message + names[i] + space

        for j in range(len(names)):
            message_Dict[names[j]] = message

    return message_Dict

n = ["Mike", "Dan", "Stan", "Max", "Rad", "Ned"]
print(everyone_sign(n))
```

This produces the following output:

```
{'Dan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned, ',
 'Max': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned, ',
 'Mike': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned, ',
 'Ned': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned, ',
 'Rad': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned, ',
 'Stan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned, '}
```

but I expect:

```
{'Dan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned',
 'Max': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Rad, Ned',
 'Mike': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned',
 'Ned': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad',
 'Rad': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Ned',
 'Stan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Max, Rad, Ned'}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one approach using list slicing.

**Ex:**

```
def everyone_sign(names):

    message = "Thank You!, Your Friends, "
    message_Dict = {}
    for idx, name in enumerate(names):
        message_Dict[name] = message + ", ".join(names[:idx] + names[idx+1:])    #list slicing
    return message_Dict

n = ["Mike", "Dan", "Stan", "Max", "Rad", "Ned"]
print(everyone_sign(n))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Dan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned',
 'Max': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Rad, Ned',
 'Mike': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned',
 'Ned': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad',
 'Rad': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Ned',
 'Stan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Max, Rad, Ned'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Example using list comprehension:

```
def everyone_sign(names):
    return {name:'Thank You!, Your Friends, '+', '.join([other_name for other_name in names if other_name!=name]) for name in names}
```

Outputs:

```
{'Dan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned',
 'Max': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Rad, Ned',
 'Mike': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned',
 'Ned': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad',
 'Rad': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Ned',
 'Stan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Max, Rad, Ned'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using list comprehension with a conditional is a simple solution:

```
def everyone_sign(names):
    messages = {}

    for name in names:
        messages[name] = "Thank You!, Your Friends, {}".format(
            ", ".join([n for n in names if n != name]))

    return messages


n = ["Mike", "Dan", "Stan", "Max", "Rad", "Ned"]
print(everyone_sign(n))
```

Output

```
{'Mike': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned', 
 'Dan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned', 
 'Stan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Max, Rad, Ned', 
 'Max': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Rad, Ned', 
 'Rad': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Ned', 
 'Ned': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a dict comprehension:

```
message = "Thank You!, Your Friends, {}".format
print({f: message(', '.join(_ for _ in n if _ != f)) for f in n})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by single for loop:

```
def everyone_sign(names):

    message = "Thank You!, Your Friends, {}"
    message_Dict = {}

    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        all_other_names = names[:i] + names[i+1:]
        all_other_names = ', '.join(all_other_names)
        sign_msg = message.format(all_other_names)
        message_Dict[name] = sign_msg

    return message_Dict
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations
from pprint import pprint


def everyone_sign(names):

    message = "Thank You!, Your Friends,"
    message_Dict = {}

    for name, others in zip(names[::-1], combinations(names, len(n) - 1)):
        message_Dict[name] = f"{message} {', '.join(others)}"


    return message_Dict

n = ["Mike", "Dan", "Stan", "Max", "Rad", "Ned"]
pprint(everyone_sign(n))
```

output:

```
{'Dan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned',
 'Max': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Rad, Ned',
 'Mike': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned',
 'Ned': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad',
 'Rad': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Ned',
 'Stan': 'Thank You!, Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Max, Rad, Ned'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are saying, give this a try:

```
def everyone_sign(names):
    message_Dict = {}
    space = ", "

    for i in range(len(names)):
        message = "Thank You!, Your Friends, "
        for j in range(len(names)):
            if j != i: #don't append to message if name will become a dictionary key
                message += names[j] + space 
        message_Dict[names[i]] = message[:-2] #remove ', ' from end of message

    return message_Dict
n = ["Mike", "Dan", "Stan", "Max", "Rad", "Ned"]
print(everyone_sign(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a separate helper function that will iterate over the elements of the input list and yield each value and its complements:

```
def items_and_complements(sequence):
    """[A, B, C, D] -> (A, [B, C, D]), (B, [A, C, D]), (C, [A, B, D]), ..."""
    for i, item in enumerate(sequence):
        yield item, sequence[:i] + sequence[i + 1:]
```

For your input list it will work like this:

```
n = ["Mike", "Dan", "Stan", "Max", "Rad", "Ned"]
for value in items_and_complements(n):
    print(value)
# ('Mike', ['Dan', 'Stan', 'Max', 'Rad', 'Ned'])
# ('Dan', ['Mike', 'Stan', 'Max', 'Rad', 'Ned'])
# ('Stan', ['Mike', 'Dan', 'Max', 'Rad', 'Ned'])
# ('Max', ['Mike', 'Dan', 'Stan', 'Rad', 'Ned'])
# ('Rad', ['Mike', 'Dan', 'Stan', 'Max', 'Ned'])
# ('Ned', ['Mike', 'Dan', 'Stan', 'Max', 'Rad'])
```

Then we can use this function to construct the desired dictionary:

```
def everyone_sign(names):
    message = "Thank You! Your Friends, "
    return {name: message + ', '.join(others) 
            for name, others in items_and_complements(names)}

print(everyone_sign(n))
# {'Mike': 'Thank You! Your Friends, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned',
#  'Dan': 'Thank You! Your Friends, Mike, Stan, Max, Rad, Ned',
#  'Stan': 'Thank You! Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Max, Rad, Ned',
#  'Max': 'Thank You! Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Rad, Ned',
#  'Rad': 'Thank You! Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Ned',
#  'Ned': 'Thank You! Your Friends, Mike, Dan, Stan, Max, Rad'}
```